# KeyPress Event in Visual Basic?

Tags: vb.net

I think this is possible, but I don't know... I want to check when the key A is pressed to move the player to the left, but for now just a messagebox.

Here is all the code I could find on the internet, it didn't work...

```
Private Sub TextBox1_KeyUp(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) Handles TextBox1.KeyUp
    If e.KeyCode = Keys.A Then
        MsgBox("Left")
    End If
End Sub
```

I am not asking how to do things when you enter stuff in a textbox, I'm asking how to run a event when you press a key.

Answer (score 4):

Try this...

```
 Private Sub TextBox1_KeyPress(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs) Handles TextBox1.KeyPress
    If Asc(e.KeyChar) = 97 Or Asc(e.KeyChar) = 65 Then
        MsgBox("hello")
    End If
End Sub
```

This should work. 97 is 'a' and 65 is 'A' in ASCII.

Comment: Some additional information, KeyUp fires up when the button you pressed gets unpressed. KeyDown fires up when the button gets pressed. If you're just capturing a press, it would be wise to use the more 'GENERAL' KeyPress event.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Private Sub TextBox1_KeyPress(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs) Handles TextBox1.KeyPress
 If e.KeyCode = Keys.A Then
    MsgBox("Left")
End Sub
```

or

```
Private Sub textBox1_KeyDown(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) _
     Handles textBox1.KeyDown
   If e.KeyCode = Keys.A Then
        MsgBox("Left")
     end if
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You probably want to set the form's KeyPreview property to true.
   Doing this makes sure the form sees all key events even if one of
   its child controls
2. Use the KeyEventArgs.KeyData property to see what key was pressed.
3. `KeyCode , KeyData and KeyValue` are members of
   `System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs` in the KeyUp and KeyDown events
   only.

Answer (score 0):

They actually simplified this from VB6.The new way with VB 2017 is...

```
Private Sub Textbox1_KeyPress(sender As Object, e As KeyPressEventArgs) Handles txtProblem.KeyPress
    If e.KeyCode = "a" or e.KeyCode = "A" Then
        MsgBox("Left")
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

So, I got one step in the right direction maybe it will help. I'm trying to give control of the paddle to the player in a game of pong and found if textbox1 is highlighted or "has focus" then these commands will execute and I can move the paddle around the screen. The problem is there is also a textbox filling up with letters in the corner of the screen as this happens I'm not sure how to get rid of just yet. Perhaps it will be useful though.

Private Sub

```
Textbox1_KeyPress(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs) Handles TextBox1.KeyPress

    If Asc(e.KeyChar) = 97 Then 'a
        Paddle.Location = New Point(Paddle.Location.X - 10, Paddle.Location.Y)
    End If
    If Asc(e.KeyChar) = 119 Then 'w
        Paddle.Location = New Point(Paddle.Location.X, Paddle.Location.Y - 10)
    End If
    If Asc(e.KeyChar) = 100 Then 'd
        Paddle.Location = New Point(Paddle.Location.X + 10, Paddle.Location.Y)
    End If
    If Asc(e.KeyChar) = 115 Then 's
        Paddle.Location = New Point(Paddle.Location.X, Paddle.Location.Y + 10)
    End If
End Sub
```

Also, you can use this command to give focus to the textbox from a different event

```
Public Sub ControlSetFocus(control As Control)

    If Control.CanFocus Then
        control.Focus()
    End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me

```
If e.KeyChar = Convert.ToChar("a") Then
    MsgBox(Convert.ToChar("a") +"enter key pressed ")
End If
```

Also you can use numbers and uppercase in ""